# Importar biblioteca Android em projeto Java: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando importar uma biblioteca Android em um projeto Java desktop. Porém a biblioteca não acha nenhuma classe que esteja relacionada ao `import android.os`.

Estou tendo dificuldades com a classe `Handler android.os.Handler`.

Alguma substituição para isso:

```
public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();
    handler = new Handler();
    Looper.loop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se a biblioteca em questão utiliza recursos do Android, como é o caso do pacote `android.os`, então você não conseguirá utilizá-la em um projeto java desktop.
A biblioteca não foi projetada de maneira a se manter livre de plataforma, então ficará restrita ao Android.

Comment: Ok. Pelo que pesquisei aqui, também cheguei a essa conclusão. Obrigado.
Você imagina alguma substituição para esse Handler?

Comment: Tem algum tempo que não trabalho com android, mas se não me engano, o Looper permite que uma thread android receba mensagens, e o handler é justamente a referência que permite a ligação da thread atual com a outra.
Qualquer callback passado para a thread deve resolver isso.
(Posso estar errado, como disse anteriormente, já não me recordo da api android)

Comment: Achei algo equivalente nessa resposta. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628751/how-to-instantiate-handler-in-java#new-answer
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r); substui o handler.post(r)
Obrigado Ricardo. Sou novo por aqui e não consigo te dar pontuação ainda.

Comment: Não se preocupe cara, estamos aqui para ajudar.